# How do I make a circular music visualizer in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

What I am getting
[image: looks like a red Spirograph]

What I want
[image: white circle with waves in it]

I am trying to create a music music visualization app and I am stuck on the circular wave pattern

```
//draw the waveform to the screen
function CircularWavePattern() {
    //vis name
    this.name = "circularWavePattern";

    //draw the wave form to the screen
    this.draw = function() {
        push();
        noFill();
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(2);

        
        beginShape();
        //calculate the waveform from the fft.
        var wave = fourier.waveform();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < wave.length; i++) {
            //for each element of the waveform map it to screen
            //coordinates and make a new vertex at the point.
            var x = map(i, 0, wave.length, 0, width) * cos(i);
            var y = map(wave[i], -1, 1, 0, height) * sin(i);

            vertex(x, y);
        }

        endShape();
        pop();
    };
}
```

Comment: Instead of map, you need `circlecenterX + cos(angle) * radius` and `circlecenterY + sin(angle) * radius`

Comment: Like This:
  for (var i = 0; i < wave.length; i++) {
   //for each element of the waveform map it to screen
   //coordinates and make a new vertex at the point.
   var x = width/2 + cos(i) * 10;
   var y = height/2 + sin(i) * 10;

   vertex(x, y);

See Full code here: https://github.com/AKOrojo/Computing-Project-1-Final-Project